# Dynamic Form Generation C# MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to make a form where administrator can add multiple questions on clicking "Add Question". 
Each question administrator would give answer options and will select the right option among them.
This form would be binded with the ViewModel since two tables are involved in it (ie: Question Table & Answer Options Table)

[UI looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFR0p.png)

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to enable such functionality ?